Query DSL - Regexp inside bool
I'm using OpenSearch Dashboard to look for specific logs. I need to filter them using query DSL to get following results:
"sText": ".*task started" OR "sText":".*task finished"
I am able to filter using "query regexp" for one value
{
  "query": {
       "regexp":{
            "sText":".*task finished"
            }
        }
} 

or for one of the 2 specific values using "should" :
{
  "query": {
   
        "bool":{
            "should":[
            {
                "match":{
                    "sText":"XYDB task finished"
                }
            },
            {
             "match":{
                  "sText": "XYDB task started"
             }   
            }
            ]
        }
     
    
  }
}

How do I combine these so I can use the regexp inside the "should" query?
I tried:
{
  "query": {
    
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
                "regexp":{
                    "sText": ".*task started"
                }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
                "regexp":{
                    "sText": ".*task finished"
                }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  }
}


and also:
{
  "query": {
    "regexp":
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
                {
                    "sTask": ".*task started"
                }
            
          },
          {
            "match": {
                
                    "sTask": ".*task finished"
                }
            
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


I also tried to use "wildcards" instead of "regexp" but the results were the same.

So I found an answer to this after all.
The problem was I was using "match" in combination with "regexp" but the "regexp" should be used INSTEAD of "match" as it looks for exact matches.
The filter should look like:
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
        {
            "regexp":{
                "sText": ".*task started"
                }
        },
        {
            "regexp":{
                "sText": ".*task finished"
            }
        }          
        ]
    }
  }
}

